# How to reset appearance of the system settings application?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes

After I upgraded my system from kubuntu 19.04 to 20.04, I had experimented a bit with switching global theme & plasma style. Somehow, the appearance of the systems setting application seems to be stuck in a mode where it is very difficult to read the audio settings as shown below.

I tried switching global theme, plasma style, application style without: the systems settings application keeps the same appearance.

What do I need to do to force the appearance of the systems settings application back to a reasonable configuration where it is legible?

[image: My illegible systems settings application window]

Comment: 19.04 to 20.04 was never a supported upgrade path because 19.04 had already reached end of life when 20.04 was released. Bugs are expected when not following a supported upgrade path. You might have to perform a clean install.  Sparing that being the cause of your issue, if it was caused by your "experimentation", then logically, it should be undone if you revert the changes you made when experimenting.

Comment: After the update, I did run into problems and had to reinstall 20.04. I'm not keen on doing that again. It is baffling to me that one can easily mess up a system to the point of being unusable (the audio settings become illegible). If recovering from that really requires a re-install, then that would make experimenting with appearance settings very frustrating for a lot of users. Surely there must be a way to fix this without having to re-install from scratch.